# How to Capture keydown event of a Label?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I added the event, I click in the label and press any key, but it doest go to the method. How can I capture?

Comment: Labels are meant to be clicked, typed on, focussed. It's a message from our overlords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could disguise a text box to look like a label.

Comment: This qualifies as shenanigans.

Comment: SHENANIGANS! But really, controls are more about behavior, not appearance. Especially in WPF, if you need a something that's clickable why not just restyle a button?  If you need something that receives key presses, a label isn't the right control.  What do you want to do, following the keypress?

Comment: yes, worked perfectly. I can even set textobox transparent to look like label.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think labels can receive keyboard input. It will go to the control with focus, and labels can never have focus (by default, I guess you might pull some shenanigans though), most likely your events are going to your main form.

Answer (score 0):

To add content beyond my other comment.  Have you looked at something like input bindings for what you are trying to do?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx