# Keydown Event of a Label

Tags: c#, wpf

I have used a runtime draggable label in WPF which i found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71792/WPF-Draggable-Label).

I want to move this label on key up and down button. The problem is that label does not register key down or key up event. How to do this?

I was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356426/how-to-capture-keydown-event-of-a-label) that i should disguise a textbox as a label but then the dragging facility disappears. How to achieve label key down without disguise?

Comment: Catch the key presses at the forms level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the label by this way-

1. Add Mouse down event to the label and give it focus-

   ```
   private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       label1.Focus();
   }
   ```
2. Set this property for this label-

   ```
   Focusable="True"
   ```

This way the label will respond to your key down event.